# dart import to define <T>

Tags: dart

I wish to check any list pass into `checkList` function. What import I should use for `<T>`. VS Code no suggest a Quick Fix for this.

[image]

```
The name 'T' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument.
Try correcting the name to an existing type, or defining a type named 'T'.
```

Comment: You don't need an import; you need to make your function *generic*: `checkList<T>(List<T> list)`. Also see https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#using-generic-methods

Answer (score 1):

If you want to type safe you should do this

```dart
void checkList<T>(List<T> list){
   // ... 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to check any list with any contents, you should use:

```dart
void checkListObject(List<Object> list) {
  // ...
}
```

If you want to enforce that the list has a concrete type, but you don't know what that is ahead of time, you can pass a type parameter to the function:

```dart
void checkListT<T>(List<T> list) {
  // ...
}
```

This has the following behaviour:

```dart
checkListObject(["hello", 123]);  // allowed
checkListObject([123, 234]);  // allowed

checkListT(["hello", 123]);  // allowed, T is Object
checkListT<String>(["hello", "world"]);  // allowed, T is String
checkListT<String>([123, 234]);  // not allowed, T is String but given List<int>
checkListT<String>([123, "hello"]);  // not allowed, T is String but given List<Object>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object` instead of `T`.

```
void checkList(List<Object> list){
     
}
```

Comment: While not incorrect, this isn't the best solution since you'll lose type information by effectively downcasting each element in the list to `Object`. As mentioned in other answers, creating a generic declaration is the way to go.